# Force initialization of Singleton Class

Tags: c++

I'm tracing some legacy code and I found this below of the .cpp file of a Singleton class,

```
namespace
{
    bool forceInit = (CFoo::getInstance(), true);
}
```

What is the meaning of this code? Is this a force initialization of the singleton class? Why the code exist?

Thanks

Comment: It's equivalent to `CFoo::getInstance(); bool forceInit = true;`.

Comment: The comma operator is a binary op, it evaluates the left-hand side, discards the result. Then it evaluates the right-hand side and return the result.

Comment: (1) (i) Call `CFoo::getInstance()`. Its return value, if any, is discarded. (ii) Evaluate the expression `true` (its value is the boolean value `true`). (iii) Use this value (`true`) to initialize a bool variable called `forceInit`. (2) Yes. (3) My crystal ball is out for repair.

Comment: What for are such operators used?

Comment: @KeluThatsall mainly to confuse people.

Comment: So it just want to call the CFoo::getInstance()?

Comment: @domlao Why don't you ask the author of the code?

Comment: Not here anymore.. :/

Comment: @domlao Then his intentions will remain a mystery forever. In any case, you now know the _actual meaning_ of the code, which is more important.

Comment: You can't use just call `CFoo::getInstance()` at namescope scope so he used the comma operator to call it as part of an expression for an initialisation.

Comment: @Simple Additionally, the `bool` is initialized statically on program start, so this way, the singleton is created before `main` is run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following code (**Note**: C++11 code!):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Singleton
{
  Singleton()
  {
    std::cout << "init singleton" << std::endl;
  }

public:
  static Singleton& Instance()
  {
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
  }
};

namespace
{
  bool forceInit = (Singleton::Instance(), true);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "enter main" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The effect is: when `forceInit` is initialized, `Singleton::Instance()` is called, the non-`const` ref is discarded, and `forceInit` is set to true. The reason this happens because namespace level variables are statically initialized before entering `main()`.

The problem is that you can't simple do this:

```
namespace
{
  Singleton::Instance();
}
```

One could do this:

```
namespace
{
  Singleton& singRef = Singleton::Instance();
}
```

However, I think the author didn't want to put an actual reference to the singleton into the translation unit. The comma operator allows calling `Instance()` while not actually initializing a reference to the static instance of the singleton.

**EDIT**: As to the concrete reason for doing this, if there are no comments, the author may remain the only one knowing what they intended.

**EDIT2**: Ah, BTW, the above program prints

```
init singleton
enter main
```

... just as expected.